# Are the irrotational and solenoidal parts of a smooth vector field linearly independent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, wave-equation, periodic-functions

Let $\textbf{F}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth vector field for all space. It is well known using [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) that we can decompose $\textbf{F}$ into two vector fields in $V$: $$\textbf{F} = \nabla \sigma + \nabla \times \Gamma,$$ where $\nabla \sigma$ is called the irrotational part and $\nabla \times \Gamma$ the solenoidal part of $\textbf{F}$. If both these fields are non-zero, is it true that $\nabla \sigma$ and $\nabla \times \Gamma$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\na{\nabla}\newcommand\om{\boldsymbol{\omega}}\newcommand\si{\sigma}\newcommand\Ga{\Gamma}\newcommand\F{\mathbf F}\newcommand\x{\mathbf x}\newcommand\0{\mathbf 0}$The answer is no, in general. E.g., take any nonzero $\om\in\R^3$ and let
$$\si(\x):=\om\cdot\x\quad\text{and}\quad\Ga(\x):=\om\times\x$$
for $\x\in\R^3$, with $\F:=\na\si+\na\times\Ga$. Then $\na\si(\x)=\om$ and $\na\times\Ga(\x)=2\om$ for all $\x\in\R^3$, so that $\na\si$ and $\na\times\Ga$ are nonzero but linearly dependent.

---

On a positive note, suppose that $\na\si$ and $\na\times\Ga$ are nonzero and linearly dependent, so that $\na\si=c\na\times\Ga$ for some nonzero real $c$. Then $\na^2\si=\na\cdot(\na\si)=c\na\cdot(\na\times\Ga)=\0$, so that $\si$ is a harmonic scalar field. If we assume that $\si$ is bounded above or below, then [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville%27s_theorem) will imply that $\si$ is constant. [Moreover](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1685017/96609), if $\si(\x)=o(|\x|)$ as $|\x|\to\infty$, then  $\si$ is constant. Furthermore, similarly it is easy to show that, if $\si$ is bounded above or below by a function $\si_*$ such that $\si_*(\x)=o(|\x|)$ as $|\x|\to\infty$, then $\si$ is constant -- and hence the fields $\na\si$ and $\na\times\Ga$ are zero, a contradiction.

Thus, the answer to your question becomes yes given that $\si$ is bounded above or below by a function $\si_*$ such that $\si_*(\x)=o(|\x|)$ as $|\x|\to\infty$.

On the other hand, the counterexample in the first part of the answer shows that the sublinear growth condition, $\si_*(\x)=o(|\x|)$ as $|\x|\to\infty$, cannot be relaxed to the condition that $\si_*(\x)=O(|\x|)$ as $|\x|\to\infty$.

Comment: Basically,  a harmonic vector field (including a constant one) is both divergence and curl free, and so if $F = \nabla \sigma + \nabla\times \Gamma$, given any harmonic vector field $\omega$, there exists $\tau$ such that $\nabla \tau = \omega$ and there exists $\Delta$ such that $\nabla \times \Delta = \omega$. So $F = \nabla (\sigma + \tau) + \nabla\times (\Gamma - \Delta)$. But then both the divergence free and curl free parts contain a factor of $\omega$ and so are not independent.

Comment: Though in the usual case, if $F$ is of moderate decrease then there are integral formulas for $\sigma$ and $\Gamma$, in which case both decay to zero at infinity. // The OP should look up Hodge theory, where the harmonic factor is emphasized. (There are some additional technical problems with $\mathbb{R}^3$ being non-compact. But the ideas are the same.)

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for your comments. I have been learning about this just while working, gradually, on this answer.